# Merge 2 dataframes in Pandas not merging 2nd dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, join, dataframe, merge

dataframe `A` looks like

```
      1st      name
0     01       AA
1     02       AB
2     03       AC
3     04       AD
4     05       AE
```

`B` looks like

```
   pred    1st     2nd
0  0.25    03       01
1  0.00    01       03
2  0.73    02       05
3  0.93    02       01
4  0.44    01       02
```

I want the result to look like

```
   pred    1st     2nd   1stName 2ndName
0  0.25    03       01      AC       AA
1  0.00    01       03      AA       AC
2  0.73    02       05      AB       AE
3  0.93    02       01      AB       AA
4  0.44    01       02      AA       AB
```

I tried

```
res = pd.merge(A,B, on='1st', how='outer')
```

But I get a dataframe with zero rows

How can I merge these dataframes this way?

EDIT:
The resulting dataframe I get looks like

```
   pred    1st     2nd  name
0  0.25    03       01  NaN
1  0.00    01       03  NaN
2  0.73    02       05  NaN
3  0.93    02       01  NaN
4  0.44    01       02  NaN
```

Comment: Where are the second names even coming from? And I don't see how you would be getting zero rows currently... it won't look like your expected output certainly.

Comment: the 2nd names come from `A`. So for the 1st row in `B` the `2nd` value is 03. In dataframe `A`, `03` has `name` `AC`. That's why in the result, `2nd` has `2ndName` of `AC`

Comment: dataframe `A` is longer than what I posted. What I posted was just the first few rows of what `A` looks like, as I didn't want to post the entire 1000+ rows. As for the zero rows, see my EDIT. I get rows, but `NaN` values for the `name`

Comment: It would be really helpful if you could construct a minimal, self-contained example.

Comment: I modified the example, hope it helps

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can use [merge](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/merging.html), after merging ,assign 1st to 1st & 2nd , finally drop unwanted columns.

```
df= pd.merge(df2,df1[['name','1st']], right_on='1st',left_on='1st',how='left')
df= pd.merge(df,df1[['name','1st']], right_on='1st',left_on='2nd',how='left')
df[['1stName','2ndName']] =df[['name_x','name_y']] 
df=df[['pred','1st_x','2nd','1stName', '2ndName']]
print df
```

Output

```
   pred  1st_x  2nd 1stName 2ndName
0  0.25      3    1      AC      AA
1  0.00      1    3      AA      AC
2  0.73      2    5      AB      AE
3  0.93      2    1      AB      AA
4  0.44      1    2      AA      AB
```

Comment: I also have a similar suggestion: `B.merge(A).merge(A, left_on='2nd', right_on='1st', suffixes=['_2nd', '_1st'])`

Comment: @ ayhan Yes that's much simpler solution :) a one liner

Comment: I couldn't clean up the column names though. It would require a drop and some renames but the line would be much longer so I'll just leave that as it is. :)

Comment: df['1st'] = B['1st'].str.astype(int)... convert that column to int

Answer (score 2):

Instead of merging the two dataframes, you can use map

```
df_B['1stname'] = df_B['1st'].map(df_A.set_index('1st')['name'])
df_B['2ndname'] = df_B['2nd'].map(df_A.set_index('1st')['name'])
```

You get

```
    pred    1st 2nd 1stname 2ndname
0   0.25    3   1   AC  AA
1   0.00    1   3   AA  AC
2   0.73    2   5   AB  AE
3   0.93    2   1   AB  AA
4   0.44    1   2   AA  AB
```

Comment: You can convert them to int like this: df_B['1st'] = df_B['1st'].astype(int)